# Is it possible for chrome to act as a gatt server?

Tags: web-bluetooth

For getting started and experiment with WebBT development I would like to let two smartphones (or laptops) connect with each other and transfer data (10kbps).
That would require one acting as  SERVER and the other as CLIENT by connecting to the same HTTPS website.
Would that be possible? Any code examples somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Web Bluetooth does not currently support this, however you can follow [Issue #78](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/78) for updates whenever work is done on this feature.

Comment: Good link, It seems like it a dead thread and not up-to-date? I had a look into bleno and it seems to support this, but I guess you need to have bleno installed?